# Why pd.to_numeric `errors=''` is equivalent to `errors='coerce'`

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

I am on python 3.7 and pandas 0.24.2

Setup:

```
s = pd.Series(['10', '12', '15', '20', 'A', '31', 'C', 'D'])

In [36]: s
Out[36]:
0    10
1    12
2    15
3    20
4     A
5    31
6     C
7     D
dtype: object
```

to_numeric with `errors='coerce'`

```
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')

Out[37]:
0    10.0
1    12.0
2    15.0
3    20.0
4     NaN
5    31.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
dtype: float64
```

to_numeric with `errors=''` (empty string)

```
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='')

Out[38]:
0    10.0
1    12.0
2    15.0
3    20.0
4     NaN
5    31.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
dtype: float64
```

to_numeric with `errors='ljljalklag'`. I.e, random strings

```
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='ljljalklag')

Out[39]:
0    10.0
1    12.0
2    15.0
3    20.0
4     NaN
5    31.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
dtype: float64
```

In other words, passing any string except strings `raise`, `ignore` to `errors` parameter of `pd.to_numeric` is equivalent to `errors='coerce'` .

Is this a feature or bugs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed in version 0.25.0 to validate the `errors` keyword (see [#26394](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26394)).

New behavior in 0.25.0:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.25.0'

In [2]: pd.to_numeric([1, 'a', 2.2], errors='foo')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: invalid error value specified
```

Previous behavior in 0.24.2:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.24.2'

In [2]: pd.to_numeric([1, 'a', 2.2], errors='foo')
Out[2]: array([1. , nan, 2.2])
```

Comment: Hah, so it's really a bug. I accepted and upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, this is intended behavior, given that the source code:

```
# pandas/core/tools/numeric.py
... 
coerce_numeric = errors not in ("ignore", "raise") # line 147
...
```

So it is only checking if `errors` is either `raise` or `ignore`, and otherwise `coerce` as a default.

Comment: just pandas things. :/

Comment: This is not accurate as it does not factor in the check that occurs on lines 111-112.

Comment: as @root pointing out, it's a bug (maybe intentional bug), so I accepted his answer to correctly reflect this issue. Still upvoted though.